# Why keras Conv2D makes convolution over volume?

Tags: neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network, convolution

I have a very basic question, but I couldn't get the idea about 2D convolution in Keras.
If I would create a model like this :

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3,3), input_shape=(64,64,3)),
                             tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(7,7))])
```

why the output shape is `(None, 64, 64, 1)` :

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
zero_padding2d_63 (ZeroPaddi (None, 70, 70, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_67 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 1)         148       
=================================================================
Total params: 148
Trainable params: 148
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and not `(None, 64, 64, 3)` with 148 parameters?
As far as I understand, the 2D convolution is not a volume convolution, the window is a 2D-matrix, but not a 3D-cube, so could somebody please explain why do I have 64, 64, 1 instead of 64, 64, 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct.

The 2D convolution is indeed a volume convolution. The filter is a tensor of dimensions 7x7x3. The depth of the output equals to the number of filters in the convolution; yours has 1 filter, so the depth of the output is 1.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!